# Is there any difference between ruby and ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If i want to start learning ruby on rails is it mandatory to learn ruby or any other programming language?

Comment: I don't know of a particular feature of Ruby that you do not need to use when you use Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is the framework while Ruby is the language.

Nothing is really mandatory to learn, but learning what something else is built on helps you in understanding how it works.

Comment: to start learning ruby on rails which i have to start first.First starting with ruby and then with the framework?

Comment: can you suggest me the best online tutorials where i can find the ruby working and its installation so that i could start my work

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is Ruby is a `dynamic, reflective, general-purpose object-oriented programming` language.

Ruby on Rails (ROR or rails) is an `open source web application framework` which runs on the Ruby programming language.Rails features a routing system that is independent of the web server.Ruby on Rails emphasizes the use of well-known software engineering patterns and principles, such as active record pattern, convention over configuration (CoC), don't repeat yourself (DRY), and model–view–controller (MVC). So understanding ROR needs some basic understanding of ruby.

Thus Ruby and ROR are different, ROR is just build on top of ruby.